# associate form with Object

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

`@ModelAttribute` annotation(Spring) allows for html to create an object.

For example there is a class

```
class Vasya{
int id;
String name;
//set get 
}
```

and html form

```
<form action='path'>
<input type='text' name = 'id'/>
<input type='text' name = 'name'/>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

`@controller` method:

```
@RequestMapping("/path")
    public String processSkill( @ModelAttribute Vasya vasya) {...}
```

here it works.

Question:
how can I write html form using **checkbox**es for id and name that my controller method works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont understand how to pass id using checkbox, but you can pass checkbox value that way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer check) {
    if(check != null) { // if checkbox is not selected it is null
        System.out.println(check);
    }
    return "your-view";
}
```

jsp:

```
<form action="${home}/test" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I   know this way. I want using @ModelAttribute annotation